# tensorflow tf.gather_nd do not function

Tags: tensorflow

when i use tf.gather_nd, i have some problems,my toy code is like this, when i run it ,it do not give the result
as expected. the code is like this:

```
x = tf.constant([[0.22, 0.3,0.1,0.11],[0.4,0.5, 0.6,0.99],[0.8, 0.9,0.43,0.21]])
indices = tf.constant([[1,2],[0,1],[2,3]])
b=tf.gather_nd(x, indices）
sess = tf.InteractiveSession()
cc=sess.run([b], feed_dict={})
print cc
```

when i expect the result is float result, but it got all zeros as result like

> [array([ 0., 0., 0.], dtype=float32)]

Comment: Please post **minimal** code to reproduce the problem.

Comment: x = tf.constant([[0.22, 0.3,0.1,0.11],[0.4,0.5, 0.6,0.99],[0.8, 0.9,0.43,0.21]])
indices = tf.constant([[1,2],[0,1],[2,3]])
b=tf.gather_nd(x, indices）  result is [array([ 0.,  0.,  0.], dtype=float32)]

Comment: launch your code on tf.ver.1.2.1 and tf.ver.1.3.0 both return `[array([ 0.60000002,  0.30000001,  0.20999999], dtype=float32)]`

Comment: Your code works fine for me as is...

Answer (score 0):

**Try without using tf.constant(),**

```
x = [[0.22, 0.3,0.1,0.11],[0.4,0.5, 0.6,0.99],[0.8, 0.9,0.43,0.21]]

indices = [[1,2],[0,1],[2,3]]

b = tf.gather_nd(x, indices)    

sess = tf.Session()

print (sess.run(b))
```